# War dial research

Tags: research, legal

Anyone know of any specific UK Law that would prevent the use of war dialling as part of a security research project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bearing in mind that I'm not a lawyer, you would certainly want to hire a legal eagle to evaluate whether you're contravening the [Communications Act 2003](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/21/contents), specifically:

- §125: "Dishonestly obtaining electronic communications services"
- §126: Possession or supply of apparatus etc. for contravening s. 125

Answer (score 2):

Also need to be aware that there is a bit of backlash in the UK off the back of autocallers which leave you listening to silent connections. Was trying to find an appropriate link, but can't find the article I was after. I can't see anything that explicitly prohibits you doing it in law (but IANAL) but you might just end up very unpopular :-)